# Sitecore. Don't let the content Editor Save an item if some field is not filled

Tags: sitecore

In the Sitecore content editor, how I can make it possible so that the content editor wont be able to save an item until and unless he/she filled a field data for a field lets say field name is `Email`.

I check the `Required field` with validation rules but then still the Sitecore save the item if the field `Email` in it is null. It gives an error message but still save the item.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to set `Result` paramter to `FatalError`.

I don't think you want to edit the default `Required` validation rule. The easiest approach is to create a copy of `Required` validation rule and paste `Result=FatalError` inside the `Parameters` field. Then you can use it instead of the original `Required` rule and it will not allow to save the item:

[image: Sitecore required field validator - do not allow to save the item]

Comment: Even if I type something in the field and press submit of workflow, I am getting field is required error.